# Testing Android in-app billing subscription: item not found

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I'm trying to implement in-app billing for subscription items.

I have in-app purchases working ok, but when I change the product ID to a subscription item prodID, an error message appears with the "item not found" message

What I'm doing wrong? Thank for your responses.

Regards

Comment: Can you show your code?  You are more likely to get a response if others can see exactly what you are attempting.

Comment: I'm using corona SDK and the sentence store.purchase("com.example.product") works fine but store.purchase("com.example.susbscription") doesn't, shows item not found message